# Django Wizard, multiple forms in one step

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In documentation of Django Wizard  i found code like this:

```
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}
```

So I am wondering how can i add multiple forms to single step of wizard

Comment: after spending hours on this issue, I finally have found a seem-to-be solution at: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18830 but it is not a way that satisfy me, becouse I can not use a loop as I posted to get  form fields. Any other Ideas?

Comment: the loop is used in case of a formset. Why do you need to add multiple forms in single step anyway?

Comment: maybe you are looking for formsets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make one of your forms a `Formset` containing the rest of the forms you need. You don't need to necessarily use a `ModelFormset`, you can subclass the base class and create the forms manually.

Comment: No approval of the answer yet?

Comment: This only works if you're working with multiple instances of the same form, no?

Answer (score 1):

This is now deprecated use this link: https://github.com/vikingco/django-formtools-addons

I wanted to share my settings if would be any help to anyone:

```
class BaseImageFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseImageFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Images.objects.none()


ImageFormSets = modelformset_factory(Images, formset=BaseImageFormSet, fields=('picture',), extra=2)

form_list = [("step1", CategoryForm),
         ("step2", CityForm),
         ("step3", (
            ('lastform', LastForm),
            ('imageform', ImageFormSets)
          ))
         ]

templates = {"step1": "create_post_category.html",
             "step2": "create_post_city.html",
             "step3": "create_post_final.html"}




class OrderWizard(SessionMultipleFormWizardView):
    file_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'photos')) 


    def get_template_names(self):
        return [templates[self.steps.current]]


    def render(self, forms=None, **kwargs):
        forms = forms or self.get_forms()
        context = self.get_context_data(forms=forms, **kwargs)

        #print(forms[1](queryset = Images.objects.none()))
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        form_data_dict = self.get_all_cleaned_data()
        #print(form_data_dict)
        result = {}
        instance = Post()
        #print(form_dict)
        for key in form_dict:
            form_collection = form_dict[key]
            #print(form_collection)
            for key in form_collection:
                form = form_collection[key]
                print('printing form %s' % key)
                #if isinstance(form, forms.ModelForm):
                if key == 'lastform':
                    post_instance = form.save(commit=False)

                    nodes = form_data_dict.pop('nodes')
                    city = form_data_dict.pop('city')
                    post_instance.save()

                    post_instance.category.add(nodes)
                    post_instance.location.add(city)
                    print('lastfome as esu ')

                if key == 'imageform':
                    for i in form_data_dict['formset-step3']:
                        picture = i.pop('picture')
                        images_instance = Images(post=post_instance, picture=picture)
                        images_instance.save()







        return render_to_response('create_post_done.html', {
            'form_data': result,
            #'form_list': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented an extension to the Django Wizard, which supports multiple Forms in one wizard step:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multipleformwizard